# Unable to find a numerical type in sql to store this large of value

Tags: sql-server

I am having some issues with getting this data into my sql database. It keeps giving me errors stating it can not accept the data. I have used decimal which seems to fail. The only type I have got to work was `varchar`. However, I need to be able to be able to do math equations on the data which doesn't work with `varchar`.

The value is:

```
4.453099999999999881
```

> ERROR: data conversion error (truncation)

Comment: use VARCHAR and then convert the value in program

Comment: I would perfer to avoid the conversion in the program if possible. That way I can do certain sql queries that optimize my results.

Comment: Did you try decimal with specified precision and scale, or just the default decimal with no definition? This works for me: `SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(19,18),4.453099999999999881);` (You may need a different spec depending on your largest leading values, most number of decimal places needed, etc.) Also, where does that error occur? I suspect it's in your application, or during bulk insert / BCP, not in a SQL Server query...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried some `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`?
try `DOUBLE PRECISION(52,30)`

or `FLOAT(53)` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/floating-point-types.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-float.html

Comment: float cuts my numbers off at 4 decimal points and I am attempting to keep all the values at their precise value.

Comment: DOUBLE PRECISION(M,D) ?

Comment: using mssql so that isn't an option :(

Comment: @user1626342 if you are using M$ sql why is this tagged as mysql?

Comment: FLOAT? Ugh. Avoid this when possible.